# Markdown and HTML Support - aws-samples/aws-lex-web-ui

Tags: html, aws-lambda, response, amazon-lex

I'm using [aws-samples/aws-lex-web-ui](https://github.com/aws-samples/aws-lex-web-ui/tree/master/lex-web-ui#markdown-and-html-support). I'm trying to show html response in the chat ui. I have enabled this option **ui.AllowSuperDangerousHTMLInMessage**. My lambda function returns the below response.

```
{
  "sessionAttributes": {
    "Email": "bilal@bilal.com",
    "userAgent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:81.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/81.0",
    "Name": "bilal",
    "ActionType": "others",
    "appContext": {
      "altMessages": {
        "html": "<h1>hello!</h1>"
      }
    }
  },
  "dialogAction": {
    "type": "Close",
    "fulfillmentState": "Fulfilled"
  }
}
```

But webchat UI is throwing the error, "**Sorry, I was unable to process your message. Try again later.**"

[image]

Any help would be much appreciate.

Comment: Are you able to see what's coming back from the api call to Lex? Is Lex responding correctly to the given input?

Answer (score 1):

When I had a similar issue, I received advice to put the Markdown/HTML in sessionAttribues, but I found that unnecessary (and a little complicated).

I was able to display what I needed by changing the contentType of "messages" from PlainText to CustomPayload, and that allowed me to use Markdown/HTML in Lambda-fed responses...

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).